# Default dictionary on Microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word, dictionary

I have word 2013 and when I am using the Single spaced template it spell checks in English (US) whist when I am using the normal blank document template it spell checks in English (UK). How do I change the former to English (UK)? All the other settings on my computer seem to be English (UK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the language you want to use and set as default for that specific file by clicking "English (US)" at the bottom of MS Word.

Hope that helps.

Cheers
-Kai

Comment: Where about at the bottom? and is it possible to set it as default for all files? thanks

Comment: At the status bar where the zoom buttons are located. If you do not see the language selection, right click on the status bar and click on "Language".

Comment: I can find the Language button when right clicking but it is already ticked and their is still no option to change the language? Also I do need to change for all new documents that I make using this template

Comment: Alternately you can set the default language & settings you want in "Modify Style" window. It is located at the Home tab, right click on the "Normal" style which is located at the Style row and select "Modify". At that window, you can edit the template  for that style. Click on the Format button located at the bottom left and select "Language". After modifying, press Ctrl+A (Select All) and double click on the "Normal" style.